# Why is a trigger "instead of delete" not recursive?

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-delete

I wanted to know how it is possible that I can execute DELETE query inside a trigger "Instead of DELETE" without calling the same trigger? Is it a SQL feature? Can somebody explain why it works this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> If an INSTEAD OF trigger defined on a table runs a statement against the table that would ordinarily fire the INSTEAD OF trigger again, the trigger isn't called recursively. Instead, the statement processes as if the table had no INSTEAD OF trigger and starts the chain of constraint operations and AFTER trigger executions. For example, if a trigger is defined as an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger for a table. And, the trigger runs an INSERT statement on the same table, the INSERT statement launched by the INSTEAD OF trigger doesn't call the trigger again. The INSERT launched by the trigger starts the process of running constraint actions and firing any AFTER INSERT triggers defined for the table.

It works that way because that is how Microsoft have decided. Although I can't imagine recursing would ever be useful for `INSTEAD OF`.